# SSHing to a CentOS server switches to a different user

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, users, plesk

I've started managing a CentOS 7 server for a new client that is managed via Plesk. I'm not familiar with either Centos or Plesk.

If I SSH to the server like: `ssh workspaceuser@1.2.3.4`, immediately upon connecting I see that I'm a different user. Ie `whoami` shows a completely different user.

Are there any places I can look either via Plesk or on the server to figure how/why it's changing user?

Thanks!

EDIT: Contents of /etc/passwd :

```
differentuser:x:10000:1003::/var/www/vhosts/example.com:/bin/false
workspaceuser:x:10000:1003::/var/www/vhosts/example.com:/bin/bash
acme-john:x:10000:1003::/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs:/bin/false
acme_admin:x:10000:1003::/var/www/vhosts/example.com/home.example.com:/bin/false
```

Comment: This question is not really CentOS or Plesk specific... I'd start with `sshd_config` and any dotfiles in the home of the user you are logging in as (if that exists)

Comment: Perhaps multiple users have the same uid. Check `/etc/passwd` for dups.

Comment: There are definitely users in /etc/passwd with duplicate UIDs. Would this cause it?

Comment: Yes - this machine has big issues. You have shown us 4 users with the same UID - there are use-cases for this (but they are rare - and none I know of are applicable in combination with service accounts). Further all of these accounts have been configured to prevent shell access - yet you are able to ssh in - meaning the config is compromising itself (its possible there are further accounts with this uid). This is likely just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Yes indeed @symcbean, definitely issues. This was a legacy VPS migrated from one provider to another and not really managed. Doing my best (as a web dev not a sysadmin) to clean things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by several users including these having the same UID defined in /etc/passwd. (These are all members of the same group.)

When logging in as `workspaceuser` the UID is set to 10000 but the first user in /etc/password with that UID is `differentuser`.

All users except `workspaceuser` have their shell set to /bin/false so they cannot login via SSH.